# latter / later years

Tags: adjectives, confusable

What's the difference between "later" and "latter" in the following? Are both correct and interchangeable?

> She found happiness in her later/latter years.

> His later/latter years were tranquil.

> In his later/latter years he became blind.

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable.  Collins says:

> You use latter to describe the later part of a period of time or event.
>
> > He is getting into the latter years of his career.

Whereas Longman has

> in later years: when someone is older
>
> > Using a sunscreen when you are young helps you to have healthy skin in later years.

Perhaps small difference in nuance. And possibly some dialect variation.  I think I prefer "latter" when used with a determiner

> The latter years, his latter years.

But that is only a weak preference, not a rule.